# Failure while building Vaadin

Tags: java, postgresql

I recently started with Vaadin because of a school project and I wanted to build the vaadin project with the command ./mvnw and after that I received a PSQL-Exception with the exception description: 'role "vaadinstart" does not exist'.

Exception-Output:

```
\2023-02-14 10:53:45.232 ERROR 3633 --- \[  restartedMain\] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "vaadinstart" does not exist
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) \~\[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8\]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2787) \~\[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8\]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.\<init\>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173) \~\[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8\]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:290) \~\[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8\]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) \~\[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8\]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.\<init\>(PgConnection.java:223) \~\[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8\]
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:402) \~\[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8\]
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261) \~\[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) \~\[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) \~\[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) \~\[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) \~\[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) \~\[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.\<init\>(HikariPool.java:115) \~\[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na\]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) \~\[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na\]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.\<init\>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) \~\[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final\]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) \~\[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) \~\[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) \~\[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) \~\[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) \~\[spring-orm-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) \~\[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) \~\[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) \~\[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) \~\[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25\]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8\]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) \~\[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8\]
at com.vaadin.wah.Application.main(Application.java:29) \~\[classes/:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) \~\[na:na\]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) \~\[na:na\]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) \~\[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8\]
\
```

I searched for some solution but my search wasn't successful at all.

Comment: Did the user 'vaadinstart` exist on your postgres installation?

Comment: @MarcoC yes I created one in DataGrip but it is still throwing the exception

Comment: Note that a role is not the same as a user!

Comment: I don't think this is related to building but actually running.  I also fail to
see, how this is related to/relevant for vaadin (I'll remove the tag). To me
this looks like some migrations are missing or the database that gets used is
not properly setup. Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)